# Check if a string exist in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following key `StudentMembers[1].active` but I need to check  if this key exist in the following array

```
const array= ["StudentMembers.Active","StudentMembers.InActive"]
```

How to remove the index `[1]` from `StudentMembers[1].active` and check if `StudentMembers.Active` does exist in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to remove all brackets `[<any>]` like this:

```
const key = "StudentMembers[1].active".replace(/\[.*\]/, '');
console.log(key); // Return "StudentMembers.active"
```

Then you can use `.find()` to check if array contains the key

```
const array= ["StudentMembers.Active","StudentMembers.InActive"];
const hasKey = array.find(item => item.toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase()) ? true : false;
console.log(hasKey); // Return true
```

It is strongly suggested to use `.toLowerCase()` so it would match any kind of cases.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fhkx9v3n/